# inserting into userdefined data in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi I am using SQL server 8.0 for my database.   I dont know how to insert user define data.

This is my table.

```
column name:          data type                 length         allow_nulls
study_type_id         int                          4
study_type_name       UD_NAME(varchar)             150 
study_type_abbrev     UD_NAME_SHORT(varchar)       50
order                 int
```

`UD_NAME` and `UD_NAME_SHORT` are user defined data types in sql enterprise manager. base type is varchar.
when i used insert command as below,

```
INSERT into study_type VALUES (15, 'test', 'TT',100)
```

It gives me   `"Implicit_conversion_error"` I could not see ASP webpage link to that table.

And

```
INSERT into study_type (study_type_id, study_type_name, study_type_abbrev, order) 
        VALUES (15,CAST('test' as UD_NAME),CAST('TT' as UD_NAME_SHORT),100)
```

Then it said `"type UD_NAME is not defined system type."`

Comment: SQL Server 8.0 or SQL Server 2008? 8.0 = SQL Server 2000. Can you please show the definitions for the UD types, ensure you are in the correct database, and don't try to debug from an ASP web page. Also I strongly recommend against using alias types in the first place: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-alias-types.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use user defined types in CAST and CONVERT functions

Comment: Or implicitly converted, or replace UDT by its system representative.